# Random generator creates the same numbers

Tags: java, javafx, random

While looping through a for loop which is randomly 1-10 long. I also go through a while loop. I am trying to find 6 random numbers between 1-42. I then do that again (1-10) times. Currently, these 6 random numbers stay the same. I suspect it has something to do with the seed but I could not solve it.

I tried to use both SecureRandom, Random, and via Math.random()
Nothing has worked.

The model:

```
    public static final int MAX_TIPS = 10;
    public static final int MIN_TIPS = 1;
    public static final int REQUIRED_NUMBERS = 6;
    public static final int RANGE_NUMBER_MIN = 1;
    public static final int RANGE_NUMBER_MAX = 42;
    public static final int RANGE_LUCKY_NUMBER_MIN = 1;
    public static final int RANGE_LUCKY_NUMBER_MAX = 6;

    private Random random = new Random();

    private int getRandomInt(int min, int max) {
         return random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    }

    public ArrayList<LottoTip> createOpponentTips() {
        ArrayList<Integer> opponentChosenNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<LottoTip> lottoTips = new ArrayList<>();

        //1-10
        int amountOfTips = getRandomInt(MIN_TIPS, MAX_TIPS);

        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfTips; i++) {

            int[] arrayOpponentChosenNumbers = new int[REQUIRED_NUMBERS];

            while (opponentChosenNumbers.size() < REQUIRED_NUMBERS) {

                //1-42 This here is the problem zone

                int randomNumber = getRandomInt(RANGE_NUMBER_MIN, RANGE_NUMBER_MAX);
                if (!opponentChosenNumbers.contains(randomNumber)) {
                    opponentChosenNumbers.add(randomNumber);
                }
            }
            //1-6 ---This here works
            int opponentLuckyNumber = getRandomInt(RANGE_LUCKY_NUMBER_MIN, RANGE_LUCKY_NUMBER_MAX);

            for (int j = 0; j < opponentChosenNumbers.size(); j++) {
                arrayOpponentChosenNumbers[j] = opponentChosenNumbers.get(j);
            }

            lottoTips.add(new LottoTip(arrayOpponentChosenNumbers, opponentLuckyNumber));
        }

        return lottoTips;
    }
```

LottoTip:

```
public class LottoTip {
    private int[] numbers;
    private int luckyNumber;

    public LottoTip(int[] numbers, int luckyNumber) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
        this.luckyNumber = luckyNumber;
    }

    public String getNumbers() {
        return numbers[0] + ", " + numbers[1] + ", " + numbers[2] + ", " + numbers[3] + ", " + numbers[4] + ", " + numbers[5];
    }

    public void setNumbers(int[] numbers) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }

    public int[] getNumbersArray() {
        return numbers;
    }

    public int getLuckyNumber() {
        return luckyNumber;
    }

    public void setLuckyNumber(int luckyNumber) {
        this.luckyNumber = luckyNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\nNumbers: " + getNumbers() + " Lucky Number: " + luckyNumber;
    }
}
```

Here is a System.out.println as you can see the Numbers are staying the same. Could you help me find a way to create a getRandomInt method which works all the time?

Thank you very much for your help.

```
Kerry York [
Numbers: 6, 4, 30, 15, 25, 5 Lucky Number: 2, 
Numbers: 6, 4, 30, 15, 25, 5 Lucky Number: 4, 
Numbers: 6, 4, 30, 15, 25, 5 Lucky Number: 5, 
Numbers: 6, 4, 30, 15, 25, 5 Lucky Number: 1, 
Numbers: 6, 4, 30, 15, 25, 5 Lucky Number: 3, 
Numbers: 6, 4, 30, 15, 25, 5 Lucky Number: 6]

Don Dickinson [
Numbers: 23, 29, 34, 18, 16, 19 Lucky Number: 6, 
Numbers: 23, 29, 34, 18, 16, 19 Lucky Number: 5, 
Numbers: 23, 29, 34, 18, 16, 19 Lucky Number: 3, 
Numbers: 23, 29, 34, 18, 16, 19 Lucky Number: 2, 
Numbers: 23, 29, 34, 18, 16, 19 Lucky Number: 4, 
Numbers: 23, 29, 34, 18, 16, 19 Lucky Number: 1, 
Numbers: 23, 29, 34, 18, 16, 19 Lucky Number: 1, 
Numbers: 23, 29, 34, 18, 16, 19 Lucky Number: 4, 
Numbers: 23, 29, 34, 18, 16, 19 Lucky Number: 3]

Clifford Weinstein [
Numbers: 6, 33, 13, 2, 37, 38 Lucky Number: 6, 
Numbers: 6, 33, 13, 2, 37, 38 Lucky Number: 3, 
Numbers: 6, 33, 13, 2, 37, 38 Lucky Number: 2, 
Numbers: 6, 33, 13, 2, 37, 38 Lucky Number: 1, 
Numbers: 6, 33, 13, 2, 37, 38 Lucky Number: 4, 
Numbers: 6, 33, 13, 2, 37, 38 Lucky Number: 3, 
Numbers: 6, 33, 13, 2, 37, 38 Lucky Number: 5, 
Numbers: 6, 33, 13, 2, 37, 38 Lucky Number: 6, 
Numbers: 6, 33, 13, 2, 37, 38 Lucky Number: 3, 
Numbers: 6, 33, 13, 2, 37, 38 Lucky Number: 3]

Angela Spencer [
Numbers: 12, 39, 8, 25, 40, 15 Lucky Number: 6, 
Numbers: 12, 39, 8, 25, 40, 15 Lucky Number: 3, 
Numbers: 12, 39, 8, 25, 40, 15 Lucky Number: 2, 
Numbers: 12, 39, 8, 25, 40, 15 Lucky Number: 4, 
Numbers: 12, 39, 8, 25, 40, 15 Lucky Number: 5, 
Numbers: 12, 39, 8, 25, 40, 15 Lucky Number: 4, 
Numbers: 12, 39, 8, 25, 40, 15 Lucky Number: 2, 
Numbers: 12, 39, 8, 25, 40, 15 Lucky Number: 2, 
Numbers: 12, 39, 8, 25, 40, 15 Lucky Number: 3]

Leroy McIntosh [
Numbers: 5, 23, 2, 24, 28, 3 Lucky Number: 1]
```

Comment: How are declared  (what values they have) `RANGE_NUMBER_MIN`, `RANGE_NUMBER_MAX`, `RANGE_LUCKY_NUMBER_MIN` and `RANGE_LUCKY_NUMBER_MAX`?

Comment: What are the corresponding values of ```MIN_TIPS``` and ```MAX_TIPS``` ?

Comment: Please show your `LottoTip` class. By any chance are the fields static?

Comment: You're not **clearing** `opponentChosenNumbers` between each tip. On first iteration of the `i` loop, the list is built, then on remaining iterations `opponentChosenNumbers.size() < REQUIRED_NUMBERS` is immediately false, so the `while` loop is skipped. Add `opponentChosenNumbers.clear()` right inside the `i` loop.

Comment: I only had to clear my ArrayList within the for loop. Thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You reuse the `opponentChosenNumbers` list between iterations of the outer for loop.

As such, on the second iteration, the while loop guard

```
while (opponentChosenNumbers.size() < REQUIRED_NUMBERS) {
```

is immediately false, so you don't pick new random numbers.

Move the declaration of `opponentChosenNumbers` into the for loop (or ensure it is empty before the while loop, e.g. by invoking `opponentChosenNumbers.clear()`).